# Install parallel for php7

Tags: php

I want to install [parallel](https://github.com/krakjoe/parallel) for Windows 10. For php7. However, I didn't find the [docs for installing it](https://www.php.net/manual/en/parallel.setup.php)  very clear.

I have already downloaded the latest version([0.8.0](https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/parallel/0.8.0/)). And that's it. don't know what to do next.

Do I copy and paste it into another folder? Do I use composer to download an extra interface for it? Should I have used `pecl` instead?

I just need a guide.

Comment: I would assume that if you copy these files into wherever (I'm not on Windows ATM) the other PHP .dll files are and then make sure that you include them in your php.ini file it should (either) run and report them in phpinfo or fail somehow. (Sorry for being vague but hopefully this may be of some help)

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation describes you need first to add `pthreadVC2.dll` to your `PATH`:

1. Extract the zip you downloaded.
2. Move `pthreadVC2.dll` to the `php\` directory
3. Add the path to `pthreadVC2.dll` to your `PATH` variable

Next we simply install parallel itself:

1. Move `php_parallel.dll` to the `php\ext` directory
2. Add `extension=php_parallel` to the `php.ini` file

Finally restart everything and you should be good to go!